# if condition how to return value from function php

Tags: php, function, curl

i'm trying to handelling error message from another function
i pass the respond url from curl
then in the handling value but i'm not able to echo or return the value

this is the handlingerror function

```
function gettaskIderrorhandler($s)
{
    if (strpos($s, "ERROR_WRONG_USER_KEY")) {
        return "ERROR WRONG USER KEY";
    }
    if (strpos($s, "ERROR_KEY_DOES_NOT_EXIST")) {
        return "ERROR KEY DOES NOT EXIST";
    }
    if (strpos($s, "ERROR_ZERO_BALANCE")) {
        return "ERROR ZERO BALANCE";
    }
    if (strpos($s, "ERROR_PAGEURL")) {
        return "ERROR PAGEURL";
    }
    if (strpos($s, "ERROR_NO_SLOT_AVAILABLE")) {
        return "ERROR NO SLOT AVAILABLE";
    }
    if (strpos($s, "ERROR_ZERO_CAPTCHA_FILESIZE")) {
        return "ERROR ZERO CAPTCHA FILESIZE";
    }
    if (strpos($s, "ERROR_TOO_BIG_CAPTCHA_FILESIZE")) {
        return "ERROR TOO BIG CAPTCHA FILESIZE";
    }
    if (strpos($s, "ERROR_WRONG_FILE_EXTENSION")) {
        return "ERROR WRONG FILE EXTENSION";
    }
    if (strpos($s, "ERROR_IMAGE_TYPE_NOT_SUPPORTED")) {
        return "ERROR IMAGE TYPE NOT SUPPORTED";
    }
    if (strpos($s, "ERROR_UPLOAD")) {
        return "ERROR UPLOAD";
    }
    if (strpos($s, "ERROR_IP_NOT_ALLOWED")) {
        return "ERROR IP NOT ALLOWED";
    }
    if (strpos($s, "IP_BANNED")) {
        return "IP BANNED";
    }
    if (strpos($s, "ERROR_BAD_TOKEN_OR_PAGEURL")) {
        return "ERROR BAD TOKEN OR PAGEURL";
    }
    if (strpos($s, "ERROR_GOOGLEKEY")) {
        return "ERROR GOOGLEKEY";
    }
    if (strpos($s, "ERROR_CAPTCHAIMAGE_BLOCKED")) {
        return "ERROR CAPTCHAIMAGE BLOCKED";
    }
    if (strpos($s, "MAX_USER_TURN")) {
        return "MAX USER TURN";
    }
    if (strpos($s, "ERROR: NNNN")) {
        return "ERROR: NNNN";
    }
    if (strpos($s, "ERROR_BAD_PARAMETERS")) {
        return "ERROR BAD PARAMETERS";
    }
}
```

and here is the function when i call the curl

```
function gettaskId()
{     
      $s = "ERROR_WRONG_USER_KEY";

   echo $cherror = gettaskIderrorhandler($s);

}
```

how can i get return the value from the function right

Comment: can I ask if your echoing gettaskIderrorhandler($s), if it is. try "echo gettaskIderrorhandler($s;",,,,, but if your trying to return a value try "return gettaskIderrorhandler($s);"...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change all the lines like

```
if (strpos($s, "ERROR_WRONG_USER_KEY")) {
```

to

```
if (strpos($s, "ERROR_WRONG_USER_KEY") !== false) {
```

`strpos()` returns the index, which can be `0` if the match is at the beginning, and `0` is falsey, so the `if` will not succeed in these cases.

Comment: thanks it's work and with inStr() it work without the extra condition

Answer (score 0):

Unless you only want to match those specific errors, it will make the code less repetitive if you can use a pattern to match any of the errors.

```
function gettaskIderrorhandler($s)
{
    if (preg_match('/ERROR_[A-Z_]+/', $s, $matches)) {
        return str_replace('_', ' ', $matches[0]);
    }
}
```